# CSS: Responsive design - Shrinking images in a two column list

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an unordered list containing 6 pictures. I would like the list to display the images in two columns only and then shrink the images as the window resizes.

Here is a link to a sample of jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WuwYZ/

At the moment, if your window is over 450px wide then you will see 3 or more columns, and if it is under 300px you will see 1 column.

How can I set the max width of the list to stay at 300px so that there is never more than two columns? 
And how can I get the images to shrink rather than merging into one column?

Large images in two columns:

```
 X X
 X X
 X X
```

When window extends it looks like this (but I want it to stay the same as above):

```
 X X X X 
 X X
```

Comment: if you want the images to shrink then u'll have to use javascript.. is using javascript an option for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set the width of `li` to `50%`;

```
#thumbs{
    max-width:300px;
}
#thumbs li {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#thumbs li img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WuwYZ/2/